# How to query custom performance counters using Zabbix agent?

Tags: windows, perfmon, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I was thinking of instead sending data to Zabbix Trapper I could send to Windows Performance monitor and then capture it using Zabbix Agent. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from what i gather, this might require some coding. basically, this question boils down to "how to create custom perfcounter" - when it's done and working, zabbix agent should be able to query it without any additional work.

there's some simplistic-looking howto at ms site : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317679

Answer (score 0):

1. The first part, creating a custom performance counter is pretty easy in my language of choice (C#).
2. The second part has an example in the Zabbix default items:
   `perf_counter[\System\File Write Bytes/sec]`